# DataBinding import error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have correct import for `DataBidingClass` and I can run my project without any error but in AndroiStudio it still displays error. I have tried to `Rebuild` and `Clean` project but not work.
[image]

When I import like the image bellow, the error is disappear but I think 2 ways for importing is same

[image]

How can I fix it? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: can you share your xml file?

Comment: What is the error message saying on the first image? Did you let that auto generate the import statement?

Comment: @cricket_007 @subrahmanyam boyapati `Clean`, and `Rebuild project` will not work but when I tried `Invalidate cache and Restart AndroidStudio` the error in first image is disappear. Thank you for your helping

Answer (score 1):

`Clean` and `Rebuild Project` not working
However `File -> Invalidate caches / Restart AndroidStudio` solve my problem